# Search a keyword in Mysql table with or without a space

Tags: php, mysql, space

I search for a keyword that fits the search query. And The info gets echoed out. It is like a search engine.
But I can't seem to get it to work for keywords in the database with spaces.
I have searched around a bit but can't seem to get it working.

```
<?php

// -- Database Connection --

if (isset($_POST['search_query'])) {
$search_query = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['search_query']));
echo "<div class=\"searchText\">Search</div><hr />";

//explode the search term
$search_query_x = explode(" ",$search_query);

foreach($search_query_x as $search_each) {
$x++;
if($x==1)
$construct .="keywords = '$search_each'";
}
$construct ="SELECT * FROM search WHERE $construct";
$run = mysql_query($construct);

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
if ($foundnum==0) {
echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search_query</b>.</br></br>1. 
Try more general words.</br>2. Try different words with similar
 meaning</br>3. Please check your spelling";
} else
{
echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";
while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
{
$title = $runrows ['title'];
$desc = $runrows ['description'];
$url = $runrows ['url'];
echo "
<div class='width: 400px;'>
<div class='title'><a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a></div>
<div class='url'>$url</div>
<div class='desc'>$desc</div>
</div>
<br />
";
}
}
}
else
{
echo "An ERROR HAS OCCURED ...";    
}
?>
```

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: If you echo out your generated `$construct` query, you'll see the problem - each keyword is getting appending onto the WHERE clause, with no AND or OR between them. If you have two terms, your SQL is invalid. You should instead push each term into an array, and then implode that with OR (or AND) as the glue to generate the string you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `$search_query_x = explode(" ",$search_query);` your blankspaces get removed due to the splitting by blankspaces.

You have to chose a new delimiter for the data to seperate - like a comma instead of a blankspace.

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_query = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['search_query']));
```

causes your script to change spaces into URL compatible %20. Get rid of htmlentities function (which doesn't really improve security at this point) and it should be working just fine.

Htmlentities function should be used when presenting information coming from insecure sources.

Be sure to call (preferred) htmlspecialchars or htmlentities when showing the info back to the user to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS).

Also it has been noted in the comments that you are using obsolete functions.